# How do I resolve these update errors?

Tags: 9, composer

Edit: I removed a couple modules that I thought might be causing the issue and uploaded the new error code.
Edit 2: I cut some of the error code stuff to have the room to fit my composer.json file contents in.
Edit 3: the composer require line was the wrong one, fixed that.

I am trying to update my site to drupal 9 following the [Upgrading from Drupal 8 (or later) to a newer major version](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/drupal-8-and-higher) article on drupal.org. I just ran

```
composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^9' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9' 'drupal/core-project-message:^9' --update-with-dependencies --no-update
```

and it worked, however when I tried to run

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer update -W
```

I got the following error both times

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - drupal/core-recommended 9.0.0-alpha1 requires composer/installers v1.7.0 -> found composer/installers[v1.7.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.9.0).
    - drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0-alpha2, ..., 9.0.0-beta2] require composer/installers v1.8.0 -> found composer/installers[v1.8.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^1.9.0).
    - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta6 requires doctrine/common dev-master#a45d110f71c323e29f41eb0696fa230e3fa1b1b5 -> found doctrine/common[dev-3.4.x-merge-up-into-3.5.x_WbajvUjT, 2.1.3, ..., 2.13.x-dev, 3.0.0, ..., 3.5.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/jcarousel ^4.0.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/jcarousel[4.0.0].
    - drupal/jcarousel 4.0.0 requires drupal/core ^8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-beta12, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.3, 10.0.0-alpha1].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-rc3, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.3, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.0.0-alpha6].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.4.0-alpha1, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.3, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.0.0-alpha6].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.4.0-rc1, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.4.3, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.0.0-alpha6].
    - drupal/core-recommended 9.0.x-dev requires drupal/core 9.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.0.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

It looks like this is a circular issue, but I cant see in there any indication on why the update failed and what I need to fix to be able to make the update work. Do any of y'all know what I need to do to make this drupal 9 composer update work?

Here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "my/project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "role": ""
        }
    ],
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        },
        "asset-packagist": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.5.9|>=7.4.8",
        "composer/installers": "^1.9.0",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        "drupal/adminimal_admin_toolbar": "^1.7.0",
        "drupal/adminimal_theme": "^1.4.0",
        "drupal/adva": "^1.0.0-rc10",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.1.0",
        "drupal/background_image_formatter": "^1.3.0",
        "drupal/better_local_tasks": "^1.3.0",
        "drupal/bg_image_formatter": "^1.14.0",
        "drupal/blazy": "^2.5",
        "drupal/block_content_permissions": "^1.6.0",
        "drupal/block_field": "^1.0.0-rc2",
        "drupal/captcha": "^1.5",
        "drupal/ckeditor_iframe": "^2.0.0-beta1",
        "drupal/classy_paragraphs": "^1.0.0-beta3",
        "drupal/coffee": "^1.0.0-beta2",
        "drupal/color_field": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/config_update": "^1.7.0",
        "drupal/contact_storage": "^1.0.0-beta9",
        "drupal/content_sync": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/contribute": "^5.0.0-beta3",
        "drupal/cookieconsent": "^1.3.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.9",
        "drupal/devel": "^4.2",
        "drupal/easy_breadcrumb": "^2.0",
        "drupal/eck": "^1.0.0-beta2",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/entity_block": "^1.0.0-beta1",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.6.0",
        "drupal/entity_reference_revisions": "^1.9.0",
        "drupal/eva": "^2.1.0",
        "drupal/facets": "^1.8.0",
        "drupal/fakeobjects": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/fallback_formatter": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/features": "^3.12.0",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.3",
        "drupal/field_group_link": "^3.0.0-rc2",
        "drupal/field_name_prefix_remove": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.2",
        "drupal/file_mdm": "^2.1.0",
        "drupal/flexslider": "^2.0.0-beta1",
        "drupal/fontyourface": "^3.2.0",
        "drupal/fpa": "^3.0",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
        "drupal/google_tag": "^1.4.0",
        "drupal/hreflang": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/imagemagick": "^3.2.0",
        "drupal/jcarousel": "^4.0.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui": "^1.4.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_draggable": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_droppable": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0.0-beta1",
        "drupal/link_target": "^1.4",
        "drupal/linked_field": "^1.1.0",
        "drupal/linkicon": "^1.7",
        "drupal/login_destination": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/maillog": "^1.0",
        "drupal/masonry": "^1.0.0-rc2",
        "drupal/masonry_views": "^1.0.0-rc1",
        "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/media_entity_browser": "^2.0.0-alpha3",
        "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/migrate_file": "^2.0",
        "drupal/migrate_plus": "^5.1",
        "drupal/migrate_tools": "^5.0",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.2.0",
        "drupal/nodeaccess": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/page_manager": "^4.0.0-beta6",
        "drupal/panelizer": "^4.1.0",
        "drupal/panels": "^4.6.0",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.12.0",
        "drupal/paragraphs_access": "^2.0.0-rc1",
        "drupal/paragraphs_jquery_ui_accordion": "^1.4.0",
        "drupal/paragraphs_viewmode": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8.0",
        "drupal/permissions_filter": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/publishcontent": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/purge_purger_http": "^1.0.0-beta4",
        "drupal/qa_accounts": "^1.0.0-alpha1",
        "drupal/rabbit_hole": "^1.0.0-beta4",
        "drupal/rebuild_cache_access": "^1.8",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.1",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6.0",
        "drupal/responsive_menu": "^4.4",
        "drupal/robotstxt": "^1.2.0",
        "drupal/role_delegation": "^1.1.0",
        "drupal/rules": "^3.0.0-alpha6",
        "drupal/scheduler": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/schemata": "^1.0.0-alpha3",
        "drupal/search_api": "^1.20.0",
        "drupal/search_api_autocomplete": "^1.5.0",
        "drupal/search_api_sort_priority": "^1.10",
        "drupal/seckit": "^2.0",
        "drupal/security_review": "^1.0",
        "drupal/sharethis": "^2.0.0-beta3",
        "drupal/simple_sitemap": "^3.10.0",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.6",
        "drupal/slick_views": "^2.6",
        "drupal/smart_trim": "^1.1.0",
        "drupal/social_media_links": "^2.8.0",
        "drupal/sophron": "^1.1.0",
        "drupal/svg_image": "^1.15.0",
        "drupal/title_field_for_manage_display": "^2.0.0",
        "drupal/token": "^1.9.0",
        "drupal/token_filter": "^1.0.0",
        "drupal/twig_tweak": "^2.1.0",
        "drupal/twig_vardumper": "^2.2.0",
        "drupal/twitter_block": "^3.0.0-alpha0",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0.0-alpha5",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0.0-alpha4",
        "drupal/username_policy": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/vardumper": "^1.6.0",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.0.0",
        "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.6.0",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
        "drupal/weight": "^3.0.0",
        "drush/drush": "^10.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "discard-changes": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true
        }
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "enable-patching": true,
        "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": false,
        "patches": [],
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "./docroot"
            }
        },
        "installer-types": [
            "bower-asset",
            "npm-asset"
        ],
        "installer-paths": {
            "drush/Commands/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "docroot/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "docroot/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "docroot/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "docroot/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "docroot/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ],
            "docroot/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library",
                "type:bower-asset",
                "type:npm-asset"
            ]
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: These are always such a mystery without seeing composer.json but one hard issue is “ drupal/webform_embed dev-1.x requires drupal/core ~8.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev]”.

Comment: Need to see your composer.json

Comment: I just added my composer.json file. Thank you for taking the time to try and help me with this :)

Comment: Why are you attempting to install drupal/core-dev? This file has no dev dependencies. 

Here’s another blocker: “ drupal/jcarousel 4.0.0 requires drupal/core ^8”.

Comment: If you are having trouble figuring out which dependencies are the issue, sometimes installing the Upgrade Status module (in D8, without upgrading) and then running the check on the module updates page can help: https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status

Comment: @cilefen Oops, I copied the wrong line from the upgrade page. Sorry I fixed that. I had used the line I changed it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update drupal/jcarousel to a version that is compatible with Drupal 9. Its current ^4.0.0 constraint does not allow that to occur.

Comment: That fixed it! I thought I had removed it but I hadn't removed it with composer. Thanks @cilefen!